# Elasticsearch : difference between param 'index' and 'enabled'

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

what is the difference between :

```
"session_data": { 
        "type": "object",
        "enabled": false
      }
```

and

```
"session_data": { 
        "type": "object",
        "index": false
      }
```

Thanks

Comment: relevant conversation: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/whats-the-difference-between-enabled-index-and-store/10717

Answer (score 0):

As per Elasticsearch documentation

`enabled` property is used for -

The enabled setting, which can be applied only to the top-level mapping definition and to object fields, causes Elasticsearch to skip parsing of the contents of the field entirely. The JSON can still be retrieved from the _source field, but it is not searchable or stored in any other way

[Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html)

`index` property is used for

The index option controls whether field values are indexed. It accepts true or false and defaults to true. Fields that are not indexed are not queryable.

[Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html)

Hope this helps